# android: can not send out mms when wifi is on

Tags: android, mms

I want to send mms in my project in background, I write my code like this:
[How to send image via MMS in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972845/i-want-send-image-through-using-mms-in-android)

But if the wifi is on,  i can not send out my mms. 
if the wifi is off, i can send out my mms sucessful.

when the wifi is on, I got an error like this:

```
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830): org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /10.0.0.172:80 timed out
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:121)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:143)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at src.mmstest.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:280)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at src.mmstest.HttpConnectInterface.sendMMS(HttpConnectInterface.java:119)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at src.mmstest.MmsTest$MmsReceiver$1.run(MmsTest.java:57)
08-04 11:27:06.460: ERROR/HttpConnectInterface(26830):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

I think it used wifi to send out my mms.i have tried like this

```
 ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
connMgr.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,
                "enableMMS");
```

[MMS sending connectivity issues when wifi is active (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796541/mms-sending-connectivity-issues-when-wifi-is-active-android)

But the issue is still on, Please give me some help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.
Before send the mms when wifi is on, first you should call this method:

```
ConnectivityManager.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,"enableMMS");
```

When the connection is active, you need to call this method:

```
ConnectivityManager.requestRouteToHost(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE_MMS,PROXY);
```

If it returns true ,you can send out the mms sucessful.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, it would seem that it may be related to the use of AndroidHttpClient (in HttpUtils). Replacing it with DefaultHttpClient did the trick for me.